# Advantage of Key-Value Coding in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I just want to know the benefits of Key-Value Coding in Swift 4. As I am well aware of key-value coding (hold reference to properties without actually accessing the underlying data held by the property).

For Example:

```
struct Student {
    var name: String?
    var rollNo: String?
}

let student = Student(name: "aman", rollNo: "12121")
let nameKey = \Student.name
let name = student[keyPath: nameKey]
```

Here we created the the instance of Student and access the value by subscript (keyPath) but I can easily access the value by simply writing the code `student.name`.

In Objective-C, we use string as a key like given below and we could take some benefits from it

```
 [object valueForKey:@"name"]
```

My question is that is there any benefits related to coding level or memory level?

Comment: Have a look at [SE-0161](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md) to see the motivation behind the changes/improvements to Key-Value Coding in Swift 4.

Comment: Instead of referencing an object key with a simple string literal, key paths let us enforce a compile-time check that a type contains the required key—eliminating a common type of runtime error. Please read https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/whats-new-in-swift-4--cms-28939

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two key advantages are:

1. **Keys are validated:** Xcode will warn you, at compile time, if you try to use a key that is not valid.
2. **Results are strongly typed:** With the following, the compiler will know that the resulting `name` is a `String`:

   ```
   let name = student[keyPath: nameKey]
   ```

   This eliminates the need to do any casting.

The result is that it's much easier to write safe code.